# How to show eigenvalues of $X^T X$ are all non-negative

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How to show eigenvalues of $X^T X$ are all non-negative?

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please keep in mind that this is not a do-my-homework site; your last three questions have been statements of problems without any input of your own.

Comment: I just can relate it to singular values of X and i know that singular values of X are all non-negative and they are square root of  eigenvalues of $X^T X$ so they should be non-negative. but i can't introduce a proof for it.